# Differential equation: $y'+2xy=xe^{-2x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Differential equation: $y'+2xy=xe^{-2x^2}$

Homogeneous equation is: $y=e^{-x^2}$

For non-homogeneous equation:

I started with: $y_p= dxe^{-2x^2}$ and I've got $d-2x^2d-x=0$

Then I tried with $y_p = dxe^{x^2}$ and I've got $de^{x^2}+4x^2de^{x^2}=xe^{-2x^2}$

Then I tried with $y_p=e^{x^2}$ and I've got $e^{x^2}\frac{dy}{dx}=xe^{-x^2}-2xye^{x^2}$

I stopped here.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your help!

Comment: What exactly is the method you are trying and why do you think it should work? $μ$ in this context is usually associated with an integrating factor.

Comment: I will replace $\mu$ with $y_p$.

Comment: Ok, that clarifies the "what". Now add something about "why should that work", as the method of undetermined coefficients only works for constant coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

By product rule $\frac d {dx} (e^{x^{2}}y)=e^{x^{2}}(y'+2xy)=e^{x^{2}}(xe^{-2x^{2}})=xe^{-x^{2}}$. Now integrate. The answer is $y=ce^{-x^{2}}-\frac 1 2 e^{-2x^{2}}$ where $c$ is a constant. Note: $e^{x^{2}}=e^{\int 2tdt}$. This function is called the integrating factor. For any equation of teh type $y'+f(x)y=g(x)$ you can multiply by the integrating factor $e^{\int f(t)dt}$ to solve the equation.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for the comment.